# v-autocomplete with select all and clear in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

In my application, I want to implement "Filter by values" like excel or spreadsheets. But I can't implement the 'Select all' and 'Clear' button in v-autocomplete.

```
<v-col>
     <span @click="selectAll">Select all</span><span> - </span> <span @click="clearAll">Clear</span>
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="filterItems"
          :items="filterItemsList"
          dense
          outlined
          multiple
          append-icon="search"
        ></v-autocomplete>
</v-col>

<script>
    selectAll() {
      .....??
    },
</script>
```

When I'll click on 'Select all' all the items will be checked and when I'll click on 'Clear' all the items will be unchecked. Anyone, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectAll() {
  this.filterItems = filterItemsList;
},

clearAll() {
  this.filterItems = [];
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me and I am not sure why should it work.

Comment: Could you show the structure of your filterItemsList because I just assumed that it is an array of string. Also show me the structure of filterItems when you select items.

Comment: It's ok, thank you for your help, I managed the solutions. But the problem is now "After clicking on Select all" 
1. It closes the filter item list, but it should remain.
2. The checkbox is not checked the first time, it shows(checked) when I close the menu and re-open it. Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: The problem lies on how you update your filterItems. Thats why I need you to show your code. I cannot just guess what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use **clearable** option.

check this page:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/